# .NET Project Architecture

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture, oop

I have sort of a philosophical question, which also need to consider the performance impact.

We are designing a new system with many sub-services that are not related to each other, yet, some may use each other (We are using unity to avoid any decoupling).

My main question is:

- Should we break them into separate DLL's, where each service has his own dll (like product.services.serice1.dll,product.services.serice2.dll, etc.), or we should consolidate all those services into a single DLL, with difference name spaces, to seperate between them. 
  It term of performance, is there any difference between the two? also, what is the most "Acceptable" standard that being endorsed by the community (and Microsoft)?

Thanks

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the input; but non of you is really looking on the effect of multiple (over 20) different dll's need to being loaded, vs. a single, big dll. I was wondering if beside the advantage of lazy loading (and we ignore the deployment difficulties for now), is there any risk of loading large qty of DLL's? thanks!

Comment: A dll is loaded when first accessed.  So if there is an initialization stage that the system goes through at start up you can make a call to the dll's to force them to load.  This will avoid a performance lag at 'run time'.  

20 dlls == dll hell.  I'd consolidate if at all possible.

Comment: They just have *different* performance characteristics. One big assembly takes less total time to load, but it happens all at once, so it's more likely to be felt by users (or client systems if they're time-sensitive). The many-assemblies approach takes more total time to load (if you load them all), but that time is distributed - so each load event is less likely to make a significant impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your services are meant to be used together, group them in the same assembly. I've seen systems with zillions dll loaded (and solutions with zillions projects in it) with not a single instance where it was needed to cherry pick one assembly over any other. That does not preclude you from having decoupling and sane separations in namespaces.

As far as performance go, there's no real impact wrt number of dll's loaded (if you stay sane and don't go for thousands of them), but the impact is HUGE in developement if you stick with the default behavior of VS who loves to copy every reference in every project's bin/debug directory. On middle to big solutions (1000's of classes) the build process will be a lot longer and more frustrating.

Think of an assembly as a unit of deployment. If stuff is meant to be deployed together, stuff your stuff in the same assembly.

As a warning on how frustrating a project split in too many assemblies can be, look at the NUnit distribution. Over 30 different dll's, some you have to reference to be able to have unit tests, some you don't and you end up hunting for the types you need.

Answer (score 2):

Deployment is a big issue here.  If all of this functionality is going to be deployed on a single machine I would suggest a single .dll, with different namespaces for behavioral separation.  A single .dll will avoid many future issues with inter-.dll compatibility and greatly simplify deployment and installation.

Paul

Answer (score 2):

I like to develope a large system as several separate assemblies/DLLs, to promote there being an architecture. After that you can, if necessary/desirable, repackage the functionality into a single assembly before deploying it.

Comment: I also like this approach.  

Using multiple assemblies means you tend to think about the way each assembly (and its types) relates to the others (layering etc.)  Once you have something you're happy with, you can consolidate the assemblies into fewer, larger assemblies.

Comment: Yes the narrowest APIs tend to be the inter-assembly APIs. Also if it's that big a project you might have more than one development team, with different teams working on different assemblies (with well-defined inter-assembly APIs): see also Conway's Law.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd separate them into independent DLL projects to simplify development, testing, & maintenance.

Comment: In my experience, separate assemblies don't always simplify those things - often quite the contrary. (Particularly factoring in deployment.) Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly prefer breaking them into separate projects and assemblies, when they are separate "services".

If you put everything into a single assembly, any client that wants to use any service will automatically load the entire assembly.  By breaking them up, you can keep the memory usage down between separate client applications, and only load things as needed.  Technically, loading one assembly is faster than loading many assemblies, but it is not faster if you're lazy loading assemblies in terms of perceived performance.

Once the assemblies are loaded, the performance should be identical.

Comment: I had to laugh.  This is a complicated issue the many pros and cons.

Comment: It is a very complicated issue.  I'm just talking about it from a very general case. The fact that he's specifically mentioning supporting multiple types through multiple namespaces leads me to believe there is some separation of concerns within the "services", in which case, separate assemblies is most often the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Don't optimse prematurely. I'd seperate the namespaces until you have a requirement to join them as a local optimisation.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the input; but non of you is really looking on the effect of multiple (over 20) different dll's need to being loaded, vs. a single, big dll. I was wondering if beside the advantage of lazy loading (and we ignore the deployment difficulties for now), is there any risk of loading large qty of DLL's?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

.NET assemblies represent a physical artifact to package stuff you should never be used to architecture thing. In other words, use as few assemblies as possible, and preferably use only one .NET assembly. I'd advise to read [these 2 white books](http://www.ndepend.com/WhiteBooks.aspx) on how to partition your code in assemblies, namespace, layers and components.

- [Partitioning code base through .NET assemblies and Visual Studio projects](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Assembly.pdf) (8 pages)
- [Defining .NET Components with Namespaces](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Namespace.pdf) (7 pages)

Answer (score 0):

dlls load each time when we call functions in them. a big dll is not a good method. use smaller dlls, this will increase your pefomance.